# Session Redirects

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, session-variables, isset

I am trying to protect a page by making it password protected.  I am using the code below, but it doesn't work.

home.php

```
                session_start(); 



         // Process the POST variables
           $username = $_SESSION["user_name"];
              //$password = $_POST["password"];


            // Set up the session variables
            $_SESSION["user_name"] = $username;

              if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) { header('Location: login.php'); die('<a  href="login.php">Login first!</a>'); }
```

Relevant portion of login.php

```
           <?php

            session_start(); 



             // Process the POST variables
          $username = $_SESSION["user_name"];
           //$password = $_POST["password"];


                // Set up the session variables
              $_SESSION["user_name"] = $username;
```

Comment: It is necessary to define what **actually** does not work.

Comment: The code exactly as posted doesn't recognize the session or rather doesn't set it up.

Comment: Try to understand what you want to do, and try again!

Comment: Have you checked that the session cookie is actually "not present". That would a real "not carried over". Otherwise it's just a data handling bug on your part. If the cookie's there, the session will work. If it's not, it won't.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
session_start(); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) 
{ 
   header('Location: login.php'); 
   exit;
}

$username = $_SESSION["user_name"];
$password = $_SESSION["password"]; *//EDITED*
```

*EDIT:*

**On login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start(); 

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) 
    { 
        header('Location: home.php'); 
        exit;
    }
?>

<input type = 'text' name = 'login' />
<input type = 'password' name = 'password' />
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' />
```

*EDIT 2:*

After your successful login write this

```
$_SESSION["user_name"] = $_POST["user_name"];
$_SESSION["password"] = $_POST["password"];
```

This will set post in session variable 
So it will look like this
Now when you check `if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']))` it will return true and redirect to home page

Comment: Still doesn't work.  let me post the relevant part of the login script as well.

Comment: Still not working, i am not sure what the issue is, its suppose to be simple!

Comment: Can you explain in detail ,exactly what is the issue you facing ? and what is your requirement?

Comment: As soon as the login is successful they are routed to home.php, which works.  Then i am using the code above to redirect if they are not logged in.  So if they are able to login correctly it means the session must be active, but when i aplly the code it still routes them login.php

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess since you haven't really asked the question fully.  But try replacing:

```
$username = $_SESSION["user_name"];
```

with

```
$username = $_POST["user_name"];
```

Comment: What i mean is that the code that i have posted above doesn't set up the session or rather doesn't carry over the session from the login page...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are copying over an empty username, and then changing the value of an empty $username to your session's array.

You want to modify your session's information as little as possible.

so in your update page:

```
<?php

session_start();

// is the line below necessary on this page?
if ( $_POST['user_name'] != "" ) {
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['user_name'];
}

if ( ( trim($_SESSION['user_name']) != "" ) ) {
     echo $_SESSION['user_name'];
} else {
     header("Location: login.php");
     die();
}
```

Updated: removed the comment line

Comment: It still redirects to login.php

Comment: You might have never initialized the session value.

Answer (score 1):

In both your `login.php` and `home.php` you are using:

```
// Process the POST variables
$username = $_SESSION["user_name"];
//$password = $_POST["password"];

// Set up the session variables
$_SESSION["user_name"] = $username;
```

That does not make sense at all, you only set your session variable when your login criteria is met (successfull login) and nowhere else. In other places you just check if it exists / is set.

As you have not posted the part where the login is processed, it´s hard to say if there are any other errors.